# Why length of XMLHttpRequest response differs from size of requested file?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response, filesize

If actual size of file is 6327 bytes (and content-length in response header is 6327),

then why length of XMLHttpRequest response (value of xhr.response.length in code below) is different:

6085 in Chrome (Version 41) and 5961 in Firefox (Version 36)?

```
//run this code somewhere on google.com to avoid access error
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png',true);
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(e){
    if(xhr.readyState==4&&xhr.status==200){
        console.log(xhr.response.length);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Command

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','image/png');
```

or command

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/zip');
```

does not help.

Answer (score 4):

MIME type must be overridden:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png',true);
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(e){
    if(xhr.readyState==4&&xhr.status==200){
        console.log(xhr.response.length);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Actually, it not the best answer to question, but works correctly (value of xhr.response.length is equal to file size).

Comment: Ii HTML5 then following code also works correctly (even on in Explorer):

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','https://www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png',true);
    xhr.responseType='blob';
    xhr.onload=function(e){
        if(this.status==200){
            console.log(this.response.size);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();